# How to show exact number of items in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am trying to show exact (eg. 3 items) in RecyclerView. Our web application shows like this:

[image]

If I move items:

[image]

and release the mouse, it automatically comes to this:
[image]

In Android, I am showing images using RecyclerView:

[image]

**How to show exactly 3 items in the visible area of RecyclerView? How to avoid to show "half" items? Is this possible?**

RecyclerView:

```
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:id="@+id/rvProducts" />
```

One item in recycler view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/ivProduct"
        android:src="@drawable/noimage"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Code:

```
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
            = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    RecyclerView productImageList = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rvProducts);
    productImageList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    GalleryRecyclerAdapter adapter = new GalleryRecyclerAdapter(images);
    productImageList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One solution is to set `width` of each child programmatically like.

```
view.getLayoutParams().width = getScreenWidth() / VIEWS_COUNT_TO_DISPLAY;
```

And the screen size like this:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics).widthPixels;
```

Comment: What do I need to do for height?I need to show 5 items in the recyclerview visible position.

Comment: `getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics).getMetrics(metrics)` returns void in the new APIs. Use either `Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.widthPixels` or `context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics(). widthPixels`

Comment: great it's working for kotlin nee to chang syntax
context.resources.displayMetrics.widthPixels

Answer (score 13):

I have done the above task as following approach, please refers the following code

On my **`onCreateViewHolder()`** method of my **`RecycleView Adapter`**, i find out the width of the screen and than divided into **3** sections.Please check it once.

```
@Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.MY_ITEM_TO_INFALTE, parent, false);

        itemView.getLayoutParams().width = (int) (getScreenWidth() / NUMBERS_OF_ITEM_TO_DISPLAY); /// THIS LINE WILL DIVIDE OUR VIEW INTO NUMBERS OF PARTS

        return new MyCreationItemAdapter.MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }
```

From above code **`getScreenWidth()`** method which we use on above is as follow,please check it.

```
public int getScreenWidth() {

        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);

        return size.x;
    }
```

Comment: What do I need to do for height?I need to show 5 items in the recyclerview visible position.

Comment: @kgandroid have you get the solution? Or i will post the answer for you for it

Comment: That will be great man.I need to show 5 items in the visible area in a vertical recyclerview list, not horizontal.

Comment: Ok, have you posted the question here on SO so I will able to give the suggestion

Comment: No I haven't posted any separate question.Do you want it?Or you can edit this one.

Answer (score 4):

The solution that I have provided below helps in displaying pre-defined number of child items('**numOfCardViewItemsOnScreen**') in a recyclerView on the screen, also calculates the margins between these items to ***space them evenly***, by taking into account the supplied margin between the items & recyclerView's end margin's (i.e, '**marginAtRecyclerViewsEnds**')

Note that I have tested this in devices between 5.0" to 7.0" inch devices & obtained consistent result.

```
private fun configureCardViewLayoutParams(cardView: CardView, numOfCardViewItemsOnScreen: Int, marginAtRecyclerViewsEnds: Float, marginLeftParam: Float, marginRightParam: Float, marginTopParam: Float, marginBottomParam: Float): ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams {
    val numOfGapsInBetweenItems = numOfCardViewItemsOnScreen - 1
    var combinedGapWidth = ((marginLeftParam + marginRightParam) * numOfGapsInBetweenItems) + (marginAtRecyclerViewsEnds * 2)
    //Provided approx. adjustment of 2dp to prevent the extreme edges of the card from being cut-off
    combinedGapWidth += 2
    val combinedGapWidthDp = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, combinedGapWidth, cardView.resources.displayMetrics).toInt()
    //Since margins/gaps are provided in-between the items, these have to be taken to account & subtracted from the width in-order to obtain even spacing
    cardView.layoutParams.width = (getScreenWidth(cardView.context as MainActivity) - combinedGapWidthDp) / numOfCardViewItemsOnScreen

    //Margins in-between the items
    val marginLeftOfItem = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, marginLeftParam, cardView.resources.displayMetrics).toInt()
    val marginRightOfItem = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, marginRightParam, cardView.resources.displayMetrics).toInt()
    val marginTopOfItem = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, marginTopParam, cardView.resources.displayMetrics).toInt()
    val marginBottomOfItem = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, marginBottomParam, cardView.resources.displayMetrics).toInt()

    //Providing the above margins to the CardView
    val cardViewMarginParams: ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams = cardView.layoutParams as ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams
    cardViewMarginParams.setMargins(marginLeftOfItem, marginTopOfItem, marginRightOfItem, marginBottomOfItem)
    return cardViewMarginParams
}
```

The below method helps in calculating the screenWidth as the name implies

```
private fun getScreenWidth(activity: MainActivity): Int {
    var width: Int = 0
    val size = Point()
    val windowManager = activity.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager
    width = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        val bounds = windowManager.currentWindowMetrics.bounds
        bounds.width()
    } else {
        val display: Display? = windowManager.defaultDisplay
        display?.getSize(size)
        size.x
    }
    return width
}
```

Finally inside onCreateViewHolder, utilise the configureCardViewLayoutParams method depicted above & pass in the desired arguments

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyRecyclerViewHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.row_item_layout, parent, false)
    view.layoutParams = configureCardViewLayoutParams(view as CardView, 4, 12f, 4f, 4f, 8f, 8f)
    return MyRecyclerViewHolder(view)
}
```

For the sake of quick understanding, I have also provided the child items xml layout (row_item_layout.xml) So as you can see from the below xml, the root view of our child item layout is a CardView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:foregroundGravity="center">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="28dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="7dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:text="@{accountOptionsModel.title}"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView1"
            tools:text="@tools:sample/full_names" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

There is no special logic within the getCount(), just return the entire list size

```
override fun getItemCount(): Int = myList.size
```

Below screenshots are from devices of 5.0", 6.3", 7.02" respectively

[image: Consists of 5.0", 6.3", 7.02" respectively]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In a general way to achieve this there is no straight forward property that recycler view comes with.

The way this is achievable is by sending in the parent width to the adapter..

In a suedo way..

```
    Parent width = parent container width;

    InitialiseRecyclerAdapter(parent width) {
         on create view holder {
                 Set the width of ur item layout with a width that divides ur parent width in equal parts;
          }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me:

```
 private lateinit var productImageList: RecyclerView

 override fun onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView: RecyclerView) 
  {
       super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView)

        productImageList = recyclerView
  }

 override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ProductViewHolder {
        val viewHolder = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.ITEM_TO_INFALTE, parent, false)

        viewHolder.layoutParams.width = productImageList.measuredWidth / NUMBERS_OF_ITEM_TO_DISPLAY

        return ProductViewHolder(viewHolder)
    }
```

Code is in kotlin, hope it will help you.