# Android GridLayoutManager horizontal scroll with 3 items

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I have recyclerview with GridLayoutManager and I want 2 things:

1. 3 items in screen
2. horizontal scroll

#### Issue

If I don't use horizontal scroll I can have 3 items in screen but yeah it's not horizontal, but if I add horizontal option to `GridLayoutManager` then it does not show 3 items in screen row.

Current code that gives me 3 items in row (but it's vertical)

```
laundriesRecycler.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context, 3)
```

Testing code that gives me horizontal scroll but not 3 items in row

```
laundriesRecycler.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context, 3, GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
```

`layoutManager code`

```
laundriesRecycler.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context, 3)
laundriesRecycler.adapter = NearLaundriesAdapter(context, list, useraddress)
```

[image: one]

Comment: Your question is not clear enough can you some more detail about the expected result ? Do you want to snap 3 items at once?

Comment: @ADM same as screenshot I shared, `horizontal scroll` + `3 items in row`

Comment: For this you can set Dynamic width for each item according to parent Width . You calculate the width once and pass it to adapter the set the width of item inside onCreateViewHolder.

Comment: @ADM can you show me how?

Comment: Its seems a [Duplicate of This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35153618/how-to-show-exact-number-of-items-in-recyclerview) .. try this it should work . You also might wanna consider margins during calculation of width . just a Side not do the calculation only once i.e do not do it inside `onCreateViewHolder` . Give it a try .

Comment: @ADM thanks for the link, I couldn't understand anything of it and by copying that code all were red in my android studio (either code isn't  in kotlin or it's old sdk code) thanks anyway.

Comment: You don't need grid layout manager when you're showing a single row, linear is enough. Try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51224889/9241978) but alter it to modify width instead of height.

Comment: @mafortis this is not a comment of answer I've linked and it does work properly.

Comment: @Pawel my apology, I was with phone I've made mistake, it's working very well thank you.